# webservice - function and method

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, web-services

I'm using visual studio 2010 to do webservice with a mysql db.

I've done up a function that check password and return the password (current password),
and in the webmethod, I call the function to verify that the old password before changing is equal before proceeding to call the mysql command. but even when i double check and copy paste the user/pass from the db directly, the web method call return invalid. Can anyone please see where i went wrong? or is there any other information that i need to provide.
thanks for helping me out!

EDIT1: it should be the function do_check_password problem. I've tried blocking out the if loop which contain do_check_password and am able to change successfully.

My codes for function

```
private string do_check_password(string username)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ToString();
            MySqlCommand dCmd = new MySqlCommand();
            using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                mysqlCon.Open();
                dCmd.CommandText = "select password from tbl_login WHERE username = ?username ";
                dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                dCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?username", username));
                dCmd.Connection = mysqlCon;
                dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                mysqlCon.Close();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(dCmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                string currentPassword = dt.Rows[0].ToString();
                return currentPassword;
            }

        }
```

[WebMethod]

```
    public string editUserPassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {

               try
                {

                    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ToString();
                    MySqlCommand dCmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        if(do_check_password(username) == oldPassword)              
                            {
                                mysqlCon.Open();
                                dCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_login SET password=?password WHERE username=?username";
                                dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                dCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?username", username));
                                dCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?password", newPassword));    
                                dCmd.Connection = mysqlCon;
                                dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                mysqlCon.Close(); 
                            }
                            else

                            {
                                return string.Format( "invalid password");
                            }
                  }
                     return string.Format("password changed");
                  }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return string.Format(ex.Message);
                }

}
```

Comment: Returning passwords given a username over a webservice method seems crazy to me.

Comment: im using it for connection between app to db. function wouldn't be seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the method from string to BOOL and it work wonders. Probably something went wrong at the data syntax part. Here is my code incase anyone tried using string and failed and want to convert to bool

```
 private bool do_check_password(string username, string oldPassword)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ToString();
            MySqlCommand dCmd = new MySqlCommand();
            using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                mysqlCon.Open();
                dCmd.CommandText = "select password from tbl_login WHERE username = ?username and password=?oldPassword";
                dCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?username", username));
                dCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?oldPassword", oldPassword));
                dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                dCmd.Connection = mysqlCon;
                dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                mysqlCon.Close();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(dCmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }


                //string currentPassword = dt.Rows[0].ToString();
                //return currentPassword;
            }

        }
```

[WebMethod]

```
    public string editUserPassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
        {

               try
                {

                    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ToString();
                    MySqlCommand dCmd = new MySqlCommand();
                    using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        if(do_check_password(username, oldPassword) == true )              
                            {
                                mysqlCon.Open();
                                dCmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tbl_login SET password=?password WHERE username=?username";
                                dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                dCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?username", username));
                                dCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?password", newPassword));    
                                dCmd.Connection = mysqlCon;
                                dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                mysqlCon.Close(); 
                            }
                            else

                            {
                                return string.Format( "invalid password");
                           }
                  }
                     return string.Format("password changed");
                  }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return string.Format(ex.Message);
                }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your do_check_password, you have this line:

```
dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Shouldn't that be an

```
dCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

*Word of advice though, don't store those passwords in clear text. Encrypt the password with a salt using a one way hash.*

Comment: oh ok. Thanks for the advice. I just started out, so am aiming to get the basic done first, before I move on to increase security.

Comment: I read up on the syntax, and Execute Reader is something like a shortcut for using the DataAdapter and DataTable. Nonetheless I tried replacing it and the same problem still occur.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of the following line in your `do_check_password(string username)` function

```
dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And `Close()` the connection `after fill the dataset`...

Your method should be like that

```
private string do_check_password(string username)
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ToString();
            MySqlCommand dCmd = new MySqlCommand();
            using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                mysqlCon.Open();
                dCmd.CommandText = "select password from tbl_login WHERE username = ?username ";
                dCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                dCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?username", username));
                dCmd.Connection = mysqlCon;
                //dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); no need here

                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(dCmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                mysqlCon.Close();
                string currentPassword = dt.Rows[0].ToString();
                return currentPassword;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Tried but still return the same error when i run editUserPassword

Comment: returned string "invalid password"

Comment: @YangJieDomodomo debug your code and check, what db returned and what user enter in textbox....

Answer (score 1):

In do_check_password You could replace the lines beginning with **dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery** with:

```
string currentPassword = (string)dCmd.ExecuteScalar();
mysqlConn.Close();
return currentPassword;
```

*Notice that you should only close the connection once the command has executed. The dCmd.ExecuteNonQuery is not really necessary and you can forego the use MySqlDataAdapter too. If you should still have a problem, try explicitly specifying the types and sizes of your parameters, like

```
dCmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?username", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30, username));
```